# How do I generate a list of strings representing 15 minute time intervals between a start and end times in a single day using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a form where a user will be able to specify a beginning and end times using preset values. I would like to generate a list of string representations of available 15 min intervals between 9 AM and 5 PM in a single day.

Comment: What you mean by list? List<T>? An array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List<string> query = Enumerable.Range(0, 33).Select(i => 
    DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(i * 15).ToString()).ToList();
```

or

```
int i = -1;
while(DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(i * 15).Hour < 17)
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(15 * (++i)));
```

Thats for the current day, in case you are saving the values in a database.

Comment: Very cool, isn't it! The more you use LINQ, the less you use foreach.

Comment: I use it all the time, .ToList().ForEach

Comment: Cool, but I wouldn't call that clear code, especially that magic number 33 on the Range()

Comment: While the last example took a little bit to grasp, it didn't cause an out of memory error when used in ASP.Net, so I'm using it for now.

Comment: @rp: They are numbers, but not at all magic! Just read the constructor signature and it'll all be clear.

Comment: As magic tricks are clear to Penn and Teller, magic numbers are clear _when_ you understand the signatures involved. Why worry about magic numbers at all if you assume signature familiarity! (Please don't take my tone as snarky, I'm just providing another point of view.)

Comment: Shurik--what answer caused a memory problem?

Comment: @rp: 33 is not clear from any signature, you need to actually calculate that there are 33 intervals of 15 minutes between 9 and 17, also, if you change that magic number the solution won't work. OTOH, 1900-1-1 is clear from the method signature, and was put there for lack of precision of whether current date is needed or not. You can change it and the solution will still work. I think you are being obtuse just for the sake of providing a different point of view.

Comment: 33 Could be written out as 8 * 4 + 1, which is how it is calculated: 8 hours * 4 per hour + 1 overlapping

Comment: @Shurik: It will eventually, luckily you'll be dead by then. Your name reminded me of the Russian movies, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

DateTime has a .AddMinutes method. Start there. (DateTime.Now)

Comment: +1 for offering a simple explanation without feeding the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code

```
        DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0);
        DateTime current = start;
        while (current <= end)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.ToString("HH:mm"));
            current = current.AddMinutes(15);
        }
```

Comment: I chose this answer for it's clarity.

Comment: Then I tried to use it in an ASP.Net application and got an out of memory error.

Comment: Because it wasn't that clear then :-) You probably messed up the loop and made it to never terminate.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should do the trick;

```
for (var time = new DateTime(2000,1,1,9,0,0); time <= new DateTime(2000,1,1,17,0,0); time = time.AddMinutes(15))
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0:t}", time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an outer loop that has the start date given.  Have this loop use the AddDays to add a day to it until the end date.

Create a loop inside this loop and start with a time of 9AM and loop until 5PM with 15 minute increments using Silky's mentioning of the DateTime .AddMinutes Method.  At the 15 minute increments you can add to a list of strings the Time.

:)